# sed command to replace pattern including newline pattern with blank

Tags: sed, regular-expression, yaml

I have a yaml file which include text:

```yaml
 - name: flexvol-driver-host
          hostPath:
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
            path: /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec
     imagePullSecrets:
     -   name: acrrepo-bad25ec678be80
```

I have a shell script through which I am trying to remove `-   name:.*` for **`imagePullSecrets:`** only. So If **`imagePullSecrets:`** have `-   name:` below it then it should be removed and only `imagePullSecrets:` should be preserved.

Please can someone help me to do this with sed.

**PS:** There can be more than one entry of **`imagePullSecrets:`** in yaml doc. So all **`imagePullSecrets:`** should be handled in same way as mentioned above.

Comment: sed is not good at processing multi-line input or structured text like yaml.  Use a YAML parser.  There are many to choose from, including command-line tools like [yq](http://mikefarah.github.io/yq/).  Most languages have decent yaml parser libraries - e.g. perl's [YAML](https://metacpan.org/release/YAML) and python's [pyyaml](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml)

Comment: Your YAML document seems to be mis-formatted (the second line has too much indentation). Could you please double check the formatting and make sure it's valid YAML? This matters since you want to delete a particular "path" in the document's structure. This task is _trivial_ to solve with common command-line YAML parsing tools. Line-oriented text-editing tools like `sed` are not generally suitable for manipulating structured document formats.

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to remove only the first entry from the `imagePullSecrets` array, or whether you want to remove all entries if there are more than one (basically setting the array to `null`).  It is further unclear whether there are more `imagePullSecrets` arrays in the file that should be handled in the same way.

Comment: @they: I have edited the que. There can be multiple entries of  `imagePullSecrets:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU sed can do so if the specified lines follow one after another:

```
sed 'N;/\s*imagePullSecrets:\n[ -]*name:/!{P;D};s/\n.*//' file
```

There are always two lines in the editor buffer (pattern space). If they do not match the pattern, then the first line is printed by `P` then deleted by the `D` command and the execution is transferred to the very beginning of the script, i.e. the next line is added to the remaining second line by the `N` command and again in cycle checked for a match with the pattern. If the pattern is found, then the `{P;D}` commands are skipped, the cycle is interrupted and the substitution command `s///` is executed, it cuts off the second line in the buffer. In the next step, the editor begins to work by loading the next line in empty buffer and if it is not the last one, adds another line by the `N` command. If at the moment of execution of the `N` command, it turns out that the last line has already been loaded into the buffer, then the further execution of the script is terminated and one line existing in the buffer is printed.

It must be admitted that `sed` from FreeBSD behaves differently and does not display the last odd line.

`D`   *...delete text in the pattern space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.*

Answer (score 0):

As you example document is supposed to be a YAML file, I looked up some other YAML files related to Kubernetes, it appears your file might actually look something like the following:

```yaml
spec:
  container:
    - name: flexvol-driver-host
      hostPath:
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
        path: /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: acrrepo-bad25ec678be80
```

Note that indentation in YAML files is important.

To delete the full contents of each `imagePullSecrets` section in this data, without removing the section itself, we might use `yq` (from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) like so:

```bsh
$ yq -y '(.. | .imagePullSecrets? // empty) |= null' file.yml
spec:
  container:
    - name: flexvol-driver-host
      hostPath:
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
        path: /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec
  imagePullSecrets: null
```

This recurses into each part of the document, pulling out any section that is called `imagePullSecrets` and sets its value to `null`.  This is equivalent of emptying the section.

Use `yq` with its `--in-place` (or `-i`) option to make an in-place edit in the given file.